# dygraphs - limiting the change of y axis range when zooming

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

When I am zooming the chart then the Y scale is changing automatically to select the range fitting to the values limited by x.

I know valueRange param where I can fix the range, but I am searching for an option to define some maximal range.

So that the Y scale is changing when zooming , but the scale is limited by some parameter

Answer (score 0):

In the interest of clarity and brevity, I have omitted some things - such as the creation process.

You would be able to do something similar to limit the minimum range.

```
g = new Dygraph(
    ... your parameters ...
);

window.intervalId = setInterval(
    function(){
        var extents = g.yAxisRange();
        var lowerExtent = extents[0];
        var upperExtent = extents[1];

        if(upperExtent > MY_MAX_DESIRED){
            var range = [lowerExtent, MY_MAX_DESIRED];
            g.updateOptions('valueRange': range);
        }
    },
    500
);
```

Using the above solution, you would notice a half-second 'glitch' on zooming when the range it set.  As an alternative, you could also use the zoomCallBack, specified when you create the graph object:

```
g = new Dygraph(
    document.getElementById("div_g"),
    [[0,0]],
    {
        zoomCallBack: function(minDate, maxDate, yRanges){
            var extents = yRanges;
            var lowerExtent = extents[0];
            var upperExtent = extents[1];

            if(upperExtent > MY_MAX_DESIRED){
                var range = [lowerExtent, MY_MAX_DESIRED];
                g.updateOptions('valueRange': range);
            }
        }
    }
);
```

One caveat, I haven't tested the above solutions.  I just believe they should work.  Good luck!

Comment: I'd recommend the `zoomCallback` approach.

Comment: updateOptions must have curly braces inside first, otherwise an error comes.  g.updateOptions({'valueRange': range});

Answer (score 0):

thank you!
I have tried to use your suggestion
I have some issues:

```
"http://jsfiddle.net/stojak/zL6es924/4/"
```

my goal: e.g when y values in data are in between 10 and 11 then I want to zoom   on Y to 0 (10-10) to 21 (11+10)
the code is nearly working, however I do not know how to let say reset my valueRange.
the result is that after each one zoom action the range increase.

Comment: This is not an answer, this is another question!  Your problem is that you are getting yRanges as a parameter, then you are extending it by 10 in each direction each time.  Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/slightlyNybbled/zL6es924/7/

Comment: Thanks for feedback.
your modification does not solving my issue, because using double click (to unzoom) y axis is not changing again to full range - but stays 0 to 10
http://jsfiddle.net/stojak/zL6es924/8/
my goal - limit zoom in range to some range, but when unzooming then back to automated calculation of valueRange